# When is okay to use animals or a mascot say a monster, human as a website logo?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, logos

I really like some websites when they use a mascot or an animal as part of the logo. But when is it really okay to use them.

Some examples:

[image: Mailchimp logo]

[image: mashape logo]

[image: bored panda]

[image: hostgator]

Comment: Just don't use a gorilla. Or a seal.

Answer (score 2):

There are definitely situations where the branding or the image of the company fits in quite well with the use of an animal or mascot as you have pointed out. All those examples are aligned to the company/business branding or image in some ways. For example, MailChimp resonates with a personal touch that is also friendly, while HostGator is linking the name with the mascot (mountaingoat software is another example).

Another particular reason for using a mascot may have to do with the history of the company, or a personal pet that is close and dear to the owner that is incorporated as part of the startup and eventually becomes the history. IPEVO is one company that uses animals in their marketing and advertising as well, and I think the husky from Trello might be another example (may need to verify this).

Comment: When I was a child, the phrase "untouched by human hands" was popular. My older brother used to mock that by saying, yeah, they use gorilla hands." The advert usually referred to some intimately personal product or foodstuff, so the notion of animals doing the work was... unsettling. But funny to a kid!